# What is the condition for a body on an inclined plane(θ degree with horizontal) to fall freely?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

a body is lying on the frictionless wedge as shown in the figure. The necessary horizontal acceleration "a" that must be given on the wedge such that the body  falls freely is acotθ . How to get this?
Is the following approach correct?
*mgcosθ-N=masinθ ⇒ mgcosθ-masinθ=N ⇒ mgcosθ=masinθ [since N=0 during free fall] therefore a=gcotθ* 
[image: tried to solve"]

Comment: Hi Manish and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: But  according to my proof body will fall not perpendicularly downwards, is it valid for free fall? Is it not necessary to fall perpendicularly downwards towards earth?

Comment: Of course it's not necessary: throw a rock horizontally and it'll land not perpendicularly to Earth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct.  Why do you think it means the object does not fall straight down?  You found a condition such that N=0, and that's the only influence of the plane on the block.  So if N=0, the situation has to be identical to having no plane at all, which of course will lead to motion straight downward if the initial velocity is zero.  Note you are solving for a, not v, so the initial v can be whatever you want, including v=0.

Comment: But eventually it will accelerate in the direction θ with vertical as shown in figure, since net force is in that direction. So it won't fall vertically downwards.

Comment: If N=0, and the initial v=0, how will there ever be any force in any direction but vertical, so how could it produce a v that is not vertical?

Comment: Free fall is a condition where Gravity is the only force acting on the body. Here the same force has been splitted up into its components. The component mgsinθ has been balanced up by macosθ. Now only mgcosθ is the only force acting on the body, and this(mgcosθ) is not in the vertically downwards direction but it is in θ degree with the horizontal, and we know that acceleration is in the direction of force applied. So the body also accelerates in the same direction of force mgcosθ.

Comment: No,  if N=0, there is exactly one force on the block, and that's gravity.   That's free fall.  I think what is confusing you is that you are imagining that m a cos(theta) is a force on the block, but it isn't, it is simply a constraint that makes N=0.  If v=0 initially, the block just falls straight down, but the reason it can do that is that the acceleration of the plane keeps the block from touching the plane at all.  Note that any *larger* acceleration works also.  If m a cos(theta) was a force, a larger acceleration would do what?

Comment: Normal reaction(N) is not made 0, it is assumed to be zero during free fall. Please make free diagrams and explain me,it is getting more entangled. And don't you agree that there are conditions where free fall are not straight?

Comment: Sorry if my english seems to be offensive, it isn't mr primary language.

Comment: Your English is good, the problem is the physics.  You correctly calculate the acceleration needed to make N=0, but then you imagine it is some kind of force on the body, which it is not.  The way you should see this is by imagining that the acceleration of the plane is 10 times what you just calculated would be needed to make N=0.  What is N then?  What is the motion of the body then?  So you see, the acceleration of the plane does not produce a force on the body, it merely reduces N to zero.  And the only time free fall is not straight is if you start with a nonzero initial velocity.

Comment: Please draw free body diagrams and necessary explanation,(assuming you are explaining to a newbie), don't miss even a simple logic. And mail me to forduap@gmail.com. I would be high

Comment: *highly thankful, I see here it is getting more messier.

Comment: Finally finally i got you. I feel relief. Yeah the point where i did mistake all the time is assuming that calculated acceleration "a" provided force on the body, which in fact it did not exert any force but it did change Normal reaction.

Comment: Yes, you have it, that's the great thing about physics, when it all comes clear.