# Is motion of freely falling bodies always vertically downwards towards earth?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, gravity, free-fall

it can be related to [What is the condition for a body on an inclined plane(θ degree with horizontal) to fall freely?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/301269/what-is-the-condition-for-a-body-on-an-inclined-plane%CE%B8-degree-with-horizontal?noredirect=1#comment676533_301269)

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not necessary. A simple example of projectile motion with some horizontal velocity, neglecting air resistance.

Answer (score 1):

For the **vertical component**, in idealised circumstances, the instantaneous acceleration is towards the centre of the Earth.

In reality, this isn't quite accurate. The Earth isn't a perfect sphere, generally (the equatorial bulge) or locally (changes in geology etc), so there will often be a slight divergence from the vertical. This was actually used to "weigh the Earth" by measuring the way a pendulum was pulled off the vertical by the presence of a nearby mountain.